# Most efficient way to compare two __int64 numbers and get -1,0,1

Tags: int64

I have been struggling with a very simple problem... I am working with a 4 dimensional cube using AVL trees... now the problem is a performance related one... basically I have to compare billions of 64 bit numbers... (because my key is 64bit comprising the 4 dimensions of 16bits each)...

The problem is not that I can't compare 2 64-bit numbers, but rather I need to do it in as few as possible clock cycles.

Unfortunately my AVL Tree template has a signature of "int CompareKeyNode(key k, handle h)"

Under the hood I have two __int64 numbers lhs & rhs, unfortunately the contract of this method is:
1. lhs==rhs return 0
2. lhs > rhs return 1
3. lhs < rhs return -1

Now if the above method expected an __int64 number I could simply do a (**METHOD A**) return lhs - rhs;

Unfortunately it only needs a 32 bit integer, so I have to resort to something akin to ((**METHOD B**)) ie. return lhs == rhs ? 0 : (lhs < rhs ? -1 : 1)

The problem to me is that to load my data using (**METHOD A**) takes **60** secs whilst (**METHOD B**) takes **117** seconds.

Unfortunately (METHOD A) is incorrect as it loses precision on the return for casting the lhs-rhs statement.

The processing time is crucial to me and I am sure there must be a simple efficient answer which is eluding me right now...

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this? Or perhaps any suggestions?

I am working in VC++ (un-managed) but surely .NET/Java must have solved this problem in there JITing/VM stage... otherwise they would be taking a huge performance hit.

PS: Have tried memcmp() but not good enough...

Answer (score 0):

In assembly, subtract them.
zero flag set = 0
carry flag set = -1
else 1

Comment: It may actually be worth inlining assembly if speed is such a concern - C++ allows this. e.g., ***
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/edujini_inline_asm.aspx  ***
If course you may have to learn assembly. Then you may also find it's not really that much faster after all that work!

Comment: @MarineHero: Is there some reason you can't add a smattering of inline assembly just for this?

Comment: Is there a common case - e.g., majority are equal, just a few -1 or +1? Make sure that one's first. You probably can't get faster than comparing for equality! May try rearranging other things for efficiency, divide-and-conquer multithreading, etc. All of course dirty fixes.

Comment: FastAI: The following assembler 101 code has my data now loading in 72 seconds! Tx!

static int compare_key_node(key k, handle h)
{ _asm
  {
    mov        eax,dword ptr [h]
    mov   ecx,dword ptr [k]
    sub   ecx,dword ptr [eax+10h]
    mov   edx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
    sbb   edx,dword ptr [eax+14h]
    mov   eax,ecx
    jz eql
    jc nga
    mov eax,1
    jmp xxx
  eql:
    mov eax,0
    jmp xxx
  nga:
    mov eax, -1
  xxx:
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You could try `(lhs<rhs) - (rhs<lhs)`. No guarantee that it'll give an improvement (at all), but it's at least *possible* that it might...

Comment: Now why did I not think of that... Works, but still worse than what I have... takes 130 sec versus my current 117.

Comment: @MarineHero: I guess that doesn't surprise me a whole lot -- most compilers don't put as much work into optimizing "strange" code, which that definitely is...

Answer (score 0):

Really all I can see is that you should either overload or rewrite the function to accept __int64. You're always gonna get a performance loss with inline logic like that. Why can't you overload your class to accept __int64?

Comment: Sure... however... I can't do so for the following reasons:
1. I am using the same template based AVL Tree in different places
2. I would not like to impose the 64bit overhead to into the AVL class as that is more crucial than my key comparison.